# Reflection using DexClassLoader while linked to external JAR library

Tags: android, plugins, dex

I am trying to put together a plugin architecture for an Android application. I have a host application that will examine a directory for apk "plugin" files, load them in a DexClassLoader, and invoke a method to get an array of DerivedLibraryObjects.

I think the issue is that the DerivedLibraryObject extends a base class that is contained in an external JAR library. So both the host and the plugin reference this JAR. When I try to get the array of DerivedLibraryObjects I get the following exception:

```
04-01 14:26:57.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(23386): java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation
```

From what I gather, this means that object in the plugin does not match the object in the host. However, both the host and plugin applications link to a copy of the same exact jar file. If I return an object that simply extends Object, then the code works fine, but as soon as I start dealing with a DerivedLibraryObject it throws this error.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can answer my own question - the issue is that both the host and the plugin contain the external jar library so when the class loader discovers there are two versions of the same class, it bails.

What you can do is build your plugin manually by compiling everything to class files (I let Eclipse do this) and then building a jar/apk using dex by:

```
dx --dex --output=<outputdir>\plugin.jar <projectpath>\bin\
```

projectpath is the root of your android project. Your class files should be found as you descend into the bin directory.

If someone could post an ant script to do this, that would be a nice thing to add to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed the same issue with maven.
The trick is to include the common-library only in the host-app, and not to include it into a plugin.

here're parts of my projects' poms.

**common-library pom**

build it as an andriod library (using apklib packaging) and install an additional *jar file with build-helper-maven-plugin

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
   <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.7</version>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <id>attach-artifacts</id>
         <phase>package</phase>
         <goals>
            <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
            <artifacts>
               <artifact>
                  <file>${basedir}/target/${project.build.finalName}.jar</file>
                  <type>jar</type>
               </artifact>
            </artifacts>
         </configuration>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

**host-application's pom**
include dependency to the common library

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>group.id</groupId>
   <artifactId>artifact-id</artifactId>
   <version>common-library-version</version>
   <type>apklib</type>
</dependency>
```

**plugin's pom**
use *.jar dependency with the provided scope. Apklib dependency doesn't support the provided scope.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>your.common.library.group</groupId>
   <artifactId>Your-common-lib-id</artifactId>
   <version>your-common-lib-version</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Finaly create some kind of an assembler project and include in it's pom-file all three projects.

It works fine for me on with maven3 and android-maven-plugin 3.2.0